# Shapeless: Inversion of filterNot on an HList

Tags: scala, shapeless, scodec

I'm trying to write a combinator for the scodec library that converts a `Codec[K]` in to a `Codec[L]` where `K` is an `HList` and `L` is the equivalent `HList` with all `Unit` elements removed.

Implementing decoding can be done by decoding a `K` and then filtering out all `Unit` elements. Filtering out `Unit` elements is directly supported by shapeless using `filterNot`, which makes this trivial to implement.

Implementing encoding is accomplished by converting an `L` to a `K`, inserting `()` at the appropriate indices, and then delegating to the original `Codec[K]`. I'm having trouble implementing the `L => K` conversion though.

```
def dropUnits[K <: HList, L <: HList](codec: Codec[K])(
  implicit fltr: FilterNot.Aux[K, Unit, L]): Codec[L] = new Codec[L] {
    override def decode(buffer: BitVector) = 
        codec.decode(buffer).map { case (rest, l) => (rest, l.filterNot[Unit]) }
    override def encode(xs: L) = {
      ???
    }
  }
```

I've tried a few different solutions without luck. Is this possible with shapeless?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to do this without a custom type class, but that approach isn't too bad:

```
import shapeless._

trait ReUnit[L <: HList, K <: HList] { def apply(l: L): K }

object ReUnit {
  implicit object hnilReUnit extends ReUnit[HNil, HNil] {
    def apply(l: HNil): HNil = HNil
  }

  implicit def hlistReUnit[H, L <: HList, K <: HList]
    (implicit ru: ReUnit[L, K]): ReUnit[H :: L, H :: K] =
      new ReUnit[H :: L, H :: K] {
        def apply(l: H :: L): H :: K = l.head :: ru(l.tail)
      }

  implicit def unitReUnit[L <: HList, K <: HList]
    (implicit ru: ReUnit[L, K]): ReUnit[L, Unit :: K] =
       new ReUnit[L, Unit :: K] {
         def apply(l: L): Unit :: K = () :: ru(l)
       }
}

def reUnit[L <: HList, K <: HList](l: L)(implicit ru: ReUnit[L, K]) = ru(l)
```

And then:

```
scala> type Input = Int :: String :: HNil
defined type alias Input

scala> type WithUnits = Int :: Unit :: String :: Unit :: Unit :: HNil
defined type alias WithUnits

scala> reUnit[Input, WithUnits](1 :: "foo" :: HNil)
res0: WithUnits = 1 :: () :: foo :: () :: () :: HNil
```

Or in your context:

```
def dropUnits[K <: HList, L <: HList](codec: Codec[K])(implicit
  fn: FilterNot.Aux[K, Unit, L]
  ru: ReUnit[L, K]
): Codec[L] = new Codec[L] {
  override def decode(buffer: BitVector) = 
    codec.decode(buffer).map { case (rest, l) => (rest, l.filterNot[Unit]) }
  override def encode(xs: L) = codec.encode(ru(xs))
}
```

I didn't try compiling this `dropUnits` but it should work.

The trick above is just to work toward the instance you want inductively. The base case is converting an `HNil` to an `HNil`. Then if you know how to convert an `X` to a `Y`, you also know how to do two things: convert an `A :: X` to an `A :: Y` and convert an `X` to a `Unit :: Y`. And that's all you need!

Comment: It's maybe worth noting that this overgenerates instances—it'll find you a `ReUnit[Unit :: HNil, Unit :: HNil]`, for example. This may not be a problem for you, but if it is you just can add `H =!:= Unit` evidence to `hlistListReUnit`.

Comment: Thanks - I ended up carrying the constraint `FilterNot.Aux[K, Unit, L]` in `ReUnit`. Not sure how I feel about the result: https://github.com/scodec/scodec/commit/3987a842f97bc0049672d61b4f2c7f526028da4e#diff-d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

Comment: That way of splitting them up seems a little less clear to me, and I don't see why you need to duplicate `LH` and `KH` when you require them to be the same.

Comment: Thanks again! I'm not sure why I was using the evidence params -- I removed those and combined the two `Unit :: KT` cases in to a single case. These changes significantly improved compile time, and resulting implementation is very similar to your answer here, with exception of carrying `FilterNot.Aux`. https://github.com/scodec/scodec/commit/f2c45ca679f47c7aa767af950a114c75b72fc810

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend carrying around the `FilterNot` instance, which you only need on the middle method. Even then it's overkill—all you need to prove is that the head isn't `Unit`.

Comment: Indeed, removing `FilterNot` further improved compile time. `H =:!= Unit` was the necessary trick. I didn't know that type class existed in Shapeless. Awesome stuff!